# Angular 2 repeat the forkJoin 5 seconds after it's completed

Tags: angular, expand

I would like to repeat my forkJoin method every 5 seconds. The 5 second timer  should be started once the forkJoin completed and returned the result;

This is my current forkJoin:

```
  let getResult1 = this.myService.GetResult1(param1, param2);       // retrun Observable<Result1>
      let getResult2 = this.myService.GetResult2(param1, param3,param4);// retrun Observable<Result2>

       Observable.forkJoin(getResult1, getResult2)
            .subscribe(results => {
              this.result1 = results[0];
              this.result2 = results[1];
              .. start counting 5 seconds and then repeat this again and again
            },
            error => this.handleError(error));
```

Timeline i want:

Time(s): 0 - - 1 - - 2 - - 3 - - 4 - - 5 - - 6

Action:  Req - Res - - -  - - - - - - - - - -Req-...

Wait:          | wait for 5 seconds -------> |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the most elegant way. Someone with more rxjs experience may be able provide a cleaner solution, but my first thought would be to use a Subject to determine when forkJoin should be called. Then just add a timer after the forkJoin to make another request.

```
// component.ts
subject$: Subject = new Subject();

ngOnInit(){
    this.subjectSubscription = this.subject$
        .flatMap(res => {
            return Observable.forkJoin(
                this.dummy1$, // dummy observable api
                this.dummy2$ // dummy observable api
            );
        })
        .subscribe(res => {
            // after 5 seconds, call subject.next to fire another forkJoin call
            this.timerSubscription = Observable.timer(5000).subscribe(res => {
                this.subject$.next();
            })

        });
    // make initial call
    this.subject$.next();
}
```

Here is a demo plnkr (https://plnkr.co/edit/OaLIMxKKUqNXxcGp0HLW?p=preview) including subscription cleanup to avoid memory leaks

Comment: Perfect, This is exactly what I want. Many thanks LLai.

Answer (score 0):

Use an interval observable:

```
Observable.interval(5000)
          .switchMap(t => 
               Observable.forkJoin(getResult1, getResult2))
          .subscribe(results => {
            this.result1 = results[0];
            this.result2 = results[1];
          },
          error => this.handleError(error));
```

this will generate a request every 5 seconds, not necessarily 5 seconds after completion.  But it should be close enough. If it has to be EXACTLY 5 seconds, you'll need a different approach.

Comment: many thanks for the response. This was what I did first but the issue is the completion of forkJoin could take longer than 5 seconds and the outer timer start calling the next round API before receiving the response of the first call.

Comment: That’s actually ok. The previous one will cancel because that’s how switchmap operates, it cancels previous unfinished calls.

Comment: maybe, However I was getting 4 to 5 requests in the traffic when the API was slow and timer was accelerating, even after the component was destroyed.

Comment: that means you weren't canceling your prior subscriptions.  You need to unsubscribe.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `setTimeout` after completing the code inside of your callback method.

```js
export class MyComponent {

  private refreshInterval: number;
  private timeoutId: any;

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.refreshInterval = 5000; // 5 seconds.
    this.refresh();
  }

  private refresh(): void {
    forkJoin(
      this.service1.doThis(),
      this.service2.doThat(),
      // More calls...
    ).subscribe(results => {
      this.data1 = results[0];
      this.data2 = results[1];
      // More stuff...

      this.timeoutId = setTimeout(() => this.refresh(), this.refreshInterval);
    });
  }

  public ngOnDestroy(): void {
    if (this.timeoutId) clearTimeout(this.timeoutId);
  }

}
```